# Why Evolution syncs the default Google Calendar's calendar only?

Tags: evolution, calendar, google-calendar

For each Google Calendar account there is a default calendar, but the user can add more calendars for example: Family, School ...etc

I synced my Gmail account with evolution and it asks me whether I want to also sync Google Calendar and Google Contacts. I checked them, but I found that it only syncs the default calendar ignoring the rest of my calendars.

Why it does not sync the other ones automatically? And how to do that manually if it is impossible to be done automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add each calendar individually.

1. Go to Calendar
2. New - Calendar
3. Choose google calendar
4. After putting in your username, click the calendar option (the option "Default user calendar" should be selected
5. The list of all the calendars you have on google should appear. Choose one
6. Repeat 2-5 for each calendar you want to add

This way you can manage the calendars individually (e.g. enable/disable them, add an event to a specific calendar).

Check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleCalendarWithEvolution for more information.

Comment: Thank you, but ((Why)) it does not sync the all of them automatically?

Comment: I only see the calendars of my google account in that menu, not those shared with by others.

Answer (score 0):

This currently does NOT work with the "Google" entry as Calendar Type. It seems to work with caldav and the caldav link for google, though.